# Android how to create a true diagonal button?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

How to create a true diagonal button? 
So there wont be the blue line around the button.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me and give some guidelines for the xml code.

[image: Button rotated example]

Comment: If you run the app, then there won't be a blue line.

Comment: The handles are needed to resize the button at design time. You won't see them at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But the problem is when I change background color onClick listener, even if I don't press on the button but in the blue borders it is still changes the color. @BobMalooga

Comment: Unclear. The background isn't needed. If you use an ImageView or a TextView as button, the background is transparent by default. Or, depending upon your actual theme or style it might change.

Comment: @BobMalooga As I saw in android the transparent background that image has cannot be removed and that is what I was trying to do.